# Two random variables with covariance $0$ but dependent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X,Y)$ a random vector uniformly distributed on ball of center $(0,0)$ and
radius $r$.

Prove that $Cov(X,Y)=0$, but $X$ and $Y$ aren't independent.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1: Symmetry.

Hint 2: Consider cross section of a disc.

Answer (score 0):

For some $\theta$ uniformly distributed on $[0, 2\pi]$ and some $a$ uniformly distributed on $[0, r]$, we can say $X:=a\cos(\theta)$ and $Y:=a\sin(\theta)$ to get the restriction you described (in a 2D ball at the origin with radius r). Clearly $X$ and $Y$ are dependent since a measurement of one tells you about the other. Now you just have to show that $\text{cov}(X, Y) = 0$. It has to do with the orthogonality of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Actually unless the measurement happens to be exactly $r$ (assuming it is a closed ball) I'm not so sure that their dependence is obvious. Are you sure they are dependent? By any chance did you not mean for $X$ and $Y$ to be able to take values in the interior?

Comment: $P(X > {r \over \sqrt{2}} | Y > {r \over \sqrt{2}}) = 0$ but $P(X > {r \over \sqrt{2}} | Y < {r \over \sqrt{2}}) > 0$ so they are dependent.

Comment: Ah, I figured something like that would be the case! Thanks